# How can I group results and remove duplicates

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I'm fairly new to using T-SQL/SQL Server and I'm unsure of how to get the desired results with Linq.

From the code below I get the following results:

```
from com in Complaints
     join pro in Projects on com.ProjectId equals pro.ProjectId
     join cont in Contacts on com.SubContractorContactId equals cont.ContactId
     join cont2 in Contacts on com.OccupantContactId equals cont2.ContactId
     where com.EmailStatusId == null
     select new
                {
                    pro.ProjectName,
                    com.ComplaintId,
                    com.ComplaintName,
                    SubContractorName = cont.FirstName,
                    SubContractorEmail = cont.Email,
                    com.DueDate,
                    OccupantName = cont2.FirstName,
                    OccupantPhone = cont2.Phone,
                    OccupantEmail = cont2.Email
                }
```

[image: Linq results]

I'd like the results to return a distinct project with each complaint listed therein. Furthermore I'd like to group each contact within the complaint while removing duplicates. So my desired results would be a single row for each project, then within the project each complaint, and within each complaint contacts.

To help you understand I've created this outline.

```
Projects 
 - Lake Road Construction
    - Complaints
       - Foundation Cracks: ComplaintId 1, DueDate
           - Contacts
               - SubContractor
                   - Carlo
                   - CarloARosner@inbound.plus
               - Occupant
                   - William
                   - WilliamSSommerfield@inbound.plus
                   - 616-846-0467
       - Drywall: ComplaintId 2, DueDate
           - Contacts
               - SubContractor
                   * No SubContractor needed since the previous complaint has the same SubContractor.
               - Occupant
                   - Keesha
                   - KeeshaCWhitlock@inbound.plus
                   - 661-205-2018

 - Jennifer Lane Renovation
    - Complaints
       - Light Fixture: ComplaintId 3, DueDate
           - Contacts
               - SubContractor
                   - Ardith
                   - ArdithGMast@inbound.plus
               - Occupant
                   - Olivia
                   - OliviaEFournier@inbound.plus
                   - 210-530-5281
       - Plumbing: ComplaintId 4, DueDate
           - Contacts
               * Contacts have already been collected from the other complaint.
```

From what I've read I think I need to be using "group by new { }" or use a UNION. However I'm unsure in the direction I need to be going in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should group your data based on the ProjectName. The result is a list of anonymous object with a `Project` property and `Complaints` property. Each item in the `Complaints` property has a `CompId` and `Contact` property

```
var groupedResults = (from co in Complaints
    join p in Projects on co.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId 
    join cont in Contacts on co.SubContractorContactId equals cont.ContactId
    join cont2 in Contacts on co.OccupanttContactId equals cont2.ContactId
            select new
            {
                ProjecttName =  p.Name,
                ComplaintId =   co.Id,                                 
                SubContractorName = cont.FirstName,
                OccupantName = cont2.FirstName
                // Fill the other properties here please                                  
            }
).GroupBy(k => k.ProjecttName, i => i, (x, b) => new
{
    Project=x,
    Complaints =b.Select(d=> new 
    {
        CompId=d.ComplaintId,
        Contacts=new  { SubContr=d.SubContractorName, Occupant = d.OccupantName}  
    })
}).ToList();
```

Comment: You're a life saver! I would of never thought of doing it like this. Looks like I need to brush up on my Linq/Lambda.